# return subtype of baseclass in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

I have a class hierarchy and I want every class to return a type of itself and not a type of the base class

I know I must use generic in the Base class

```
abstract class Base<T> where T : Base<T>
{
    public T Foo() { ... }
}

class Sub : Base<Sub> { ... }
new Sub().Foo(); //returns Sub
```

Now my problem is what should I do if I want to inherited from a derived class

```
class SubSub : Sub { ... }
new SubSub().Foo(); //returns Sub and not SubSub
```

I could make the subclasses also generic

```
abstract class Sub<T> : Base<Sub<T>> where T : Sub<T> { ... }
abstract class SubSub<T> : Sub<SubSub<T>> where T : Sub<SubSub<T>> { ... }
```

but now I have to create 2 class for each inheritance. 1 abstract generic class that is the actual class and 1 class just do get ride of the abstract and generic

```
abstract class _Sub<T> : Base<_Sub<T>> where T : _Sub<T> { ... }
class Sub : _Sub<Sub> { ... }

abstract class _SubSub<T> : _Sub<_SubSub<T>> where T : _SubSub<T> { ... }
class SubSub : _SubSub<SubSub> { ... }
```

that would do what I want but I don't think this is a clean solution

I have to use 2 classes to be able to create new instances

```
class Sub<T> : Base<Sub<T>> where T : Sub<T> { ... }
var a = new Sub</* -- I think there is no valid option that could go here -- */>();
```

Is there a clean/best practice way to do what I want? Or is my way already clean and I just think it's ugly?

Comment: Do you mean you want to return Base<Sub> instead of Sub, or specifically SubSub. Returning Base<Sub> should be enough, since all implementions can be handled with overrides. (and Foo should then simply return Base<T> instead of T )

Comment: Why do you even care? What's so important on a method returning an exact type reference? If you care about overhead, I can assure you that creating a generic type for each specific type you're using will be much more important than a simple cast. You're taking inheritance and throwing the goodies away because... why?

Comment: Will that Abstract class `Base<T> where T: Base<T>` even compile?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is quite close to what you are looking for:

```
abstract class Base<T> where T : Base<T>
{
    public T Foo()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}

class Sub<T> :Base<T> where T : Base<T>
{

}

class SubSub : Sub<SubSub> 
{

}
```

Now you can create a SubSub this way:

```
var subSub = new SubSub();
SubSub subSubResult = subSub.Foo();
```

But it is now very hard to create a sub....